# Getting Height and Width for a View Failure

Tags: android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I am implementing a new class that extends CheckBox

In the constructor I am giving it a specific dimensions like this:

```
setHeight(size);
setWidth(size);
measure(size, size);
```

But whenever I call `getHeight()` or `getWidth()` it always gives me 0.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get your views width and height before it is initialized. This is the reason why you need to be more specific when you say whenever especially if you put your code in onCreate. If your view is visible at all try adding simple onClick and get and Log your width and height then and see what happens.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: No it is not like that ...It also gives me 0 even after initialization :|